# grep or detect a pattern in a character that begins with a phrase?

Tags: grep

Using Rstudio.

Have a descriptive character feature that begins with values like "I love you", "I love him", "I love my dad", "I rather love...", "I hate..", "I don't care..", "I surely love....". Many "I * love" patterns, among others.

Now I like to create a new feature that =1 if the raw feature begins with "I love*". Otherwise the new feature =0.

In SAS, i can just write such:
if compress(old_feature) in: ("Ilove") then new_feature=1; else new_feature=0;

How to do that in Rstudio? I have searched here and the closest example is below

grep("^FA_.*Sc$",names(nc_df), value=TRUE). But this captures a lot I don't want. For example, "I definitely love".

Thanks.

Comment: please add appropriate tag for rstudio (I don't know what that is)... `grep` alone would usually refer to command line tool... also, see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for formatting help